# Rails proper way to render validation errors in controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I read the documentation on Rails Validation, but didn't see much about how to work with errors in the controller.

**Question** -- Are `render :new` and `render :edit` when `.save` fails the proper way to show the errors after submitting the form?

Also, is there a way that I can keep the `polls/new` and `polls/edit` routes the same as when the form was initially loaded?

In my view I have the `@poll.errors.any? ... @poll.errors.full_messages.each do ...` block. These errors are successfully called if I have the following code in my controller, with `render :new` being the main point of interest:

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController    
  def create
    @poll = Poll.create(poll_params)

    if @poll.save
      redirect_to polls_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The form shows up, but my route changes from `polls/new` back to `polls` and none of my options are built. I also tried `redirect_to new_poll_path` but of course that starts from scratch and shows no errors.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take the following scenario: A user navigates to the form in your `new` action, enters some data, and presses "submit". By default (i.e. assuming you're using [restful routes](https://rails.devcamp.com/learn-ruby-on-rails-from-scratch/rails-routing-guide/restful-routing-in-rails)), rails will submit your form to the `create` action in your controller. Assume that the user entered some data that was incorrect and would cause `@poll.save` to fail. In your case, this code would run:

```
render :new
```

In this case, you have told rails to simply render the `new` partial again. However, since you've told rails to render the `new` partial from your `create` action, you will see `/polls` in your url bar since `/resource_name` is how rails implements the `create` portion of its restful routing system (and you've defined your resource to be called "polls".

To answer this question:

> Are render :new and render :edit when .save fails the proper way to show the errors after submitting the form?

The short answer is yes. In rails, this is typically the preferred way of showing errors to users who enter incorrect data into a form. However, if you wanted to ensure that `/edit` or `/new` was in the url bar after an unsuccessful form submission, you would need to replace:

```
render :new
```

with

```
redirect_to new_poll_path, alert: @poll.errors.full_messages
```

This solution will cause the errors in your `@poll` object to be displayed in your flash messages area (assuming you have that set up). However, I don't personally like this solution much because flash messages typically aren't intended to be used this way. This begs the question:

### Why can't I use `@poll.errors.full_messages` after a redirect?

The reason for this is because your `@poll` object (in the create action) is carrying the error messages. As soon as `@poll.save` fails, your `@poll` object will be carrying the error messages that caused the `.save` method to fail. If you were to redirect away from the create action back to the `new` or `edit` actions, the `@poll` object with the errors would be replaced by a new `@poll` object as defined in either the `new` or `edit` actions in your controller. Therefore, using `render` allows you to give the `@poll` object with the error messages back to the appropriate action so that the error messages can be displayed.

Comment: wow, thank you very much. i shared this with the rails chart and people were excited to learn that alert can be used in combination with redirect_to

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!